# HtmlHelper from html file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Is there possibility to create HtmlHelper in .cshtm file?

I tried to Create Class with helper but TagBuilder converts quotes (JavaScript code) to html encoding. This code in cshtml file will be better to debug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you use `@helper` and do:

```
@helper Message(string msg)
{
    <p>@msg</p>
}
```

To call the helper:

```
@Message("Darren Davies")
```

You can also declare functions inside the file using `@functions`

```
@functions {
   public string DarrenDavies() { return "Darren Davies"; }
}
```

And you can use it like a regular `Razor` method:

```
@DarrenDavies()
```